# Qt multimedia: cannot find -lpulse

Tags: qt, ubuntu, video

I modified .pro:

```
QT += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets
```

And I include `<QMediaPlayer>`, `<QVideoWidgets>` in main.cpp

Then I tried to build. It gives me following errors:

```
cannot find -lpulse-mainloop-glib
cannot find -lpulse
collect2:error:ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me? My system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 18):

Try `sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev`

---

From http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50938-QT-error-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lpulse-mainloop-glib:

> From: norobro
>
> Default Re: QT error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse-mainloop-glib
> On my Debian box that lib is in the libpulse-dev package. Do you have it installed?

Comment: @Annayang Then you can accept the answer by clicking on the green tick.

Comment: Thanks, for the help!!

Comment: Thanks! It was the answer. I don't know why this answer was not accepted?